# Xcode 6 autolayouts

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode6

Project works fine in Xcode 5 but in Xcode 6 I see this: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/299357raywy54kl/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-03%20at%2015.04.17.png
[image]

[image]

What are this errors about, especially the first one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having significant problems with Xcode 6 layouts; simulator and iPhone are way off from each other (simulator layout skewed, a button doesn't even appear on iPhone, but works fine on simulator).  But then, it's beta.

Edit:  Problems eliminated by going back to Xcode 5.1.1.

Edit:  Of course, all okay now in final Xcode 6.  :-)